# Configure mpich2 3.1.3

Tags: gcc, fortran, mpich

I'm trying to configure mpich library for Fortran only. When I use:

> ./configure -prefix=/home/jordi/Project/mpich-3.1.3/lib  --disable-cxx
>   --disable-gcc

I obtain this error:

> configure: error: ****  Incompatible Fortran and C Object File Types! 
>   **** F77 Object File Type produced by "  " is : : ERROR: cannot open `' (No such file or directory).  C  Object File Type produced by "gcc 
>   -O2" is : : ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped.

I don't undestand it. I'm shock that No such file, what file want?
I try to use CFLAGS=-m64 CXXFLAGS=-m64, if that's a problem with 64 bits but it doesn't work.

Can you help me?
Thanks for your time

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: And which compilers do you have?

Comment: object file type produced by "", there the command used is empty, so probably it didn't find any compiler or some other configuration of it went wrong.

Comment: Opertaing system is Ubuntu and compiler is Intel Parallel Studio XE Composer Edition for Fortran.

Comment: have you tried adding  FC=ifort F77=ifort ?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding this and doesn't work

Comment: It looks as if you might be trying to build with the Intel Fortran compiler and GCC (for C sources).  I think that with close attention to the Intel documentation you should find how to build compatible object files for linking with GCC-generated object files from the C source files.

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** I get a configure error saying "Incompatible Fortran and C Object File Types!"

**A:** This is a problem with the default compilers available on Mac OS: it provides a 32-bit C compiler and a 64-bit Fortran compiler (or the other way around). These two are not compatible with each other. Consider installing the same architecture compilers. Alternatively, if you do not need to build Fortran programs, you can disable it with the `configure option --disable-f77 --disable-f90`.

Comment: Hello, welcome on Stack Overflow, if you copied this information from some FAQ please reference it. Be sure to learn ho to properly format your posts here.

Comment: Note that the OP Wants to compile the library for `"Fortran only" and uses `--disable-cxx --disable-gcc`. Is your answer still applicable?

Comment: ok, I know it. Actually, I met this problem yesterday, but I only need to build C programs, not Fortran programs.
Installing the same bit versioin of C/C++ and Fortran compilers can solve this problem.